# Kickoff Argo workflows via REST call

Tags: kubernetes, workflow, argoproj, argo-workflows

I am exploring Argo to orchestrate processing big data. I wish to kick off a workflow via REST call that divides a large data set among a number of machines with desired resources for processing. From an architectural perspective, how would I accomplish this? Is there an REST api or maybe some libraries for Node.js that I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Argo [documentation](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/docs/rest-api.md):

> Argo is implemented as a kubernetes controller and Workflow [Custom Resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/). Argo itself does not run an API server, and with all CRDs, it extends the Kubernetes API server by introducing a new **API Group/Version** (**argorproj.io/v1alpha1**) and **Kind** (**Workflow**). When CRDs are registered in a cluster, access to those resources are made available by exposing new endpoints in the kubernetes API server.
> For example, to list workflows in the default namespace, a client would make an
> `HTTP GET` request to:

> ```
> https://<k8s-api-server>/apis/argoproj.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/default/workflows
> ```

You can find examples for Golang, Python, Java, Ruby, OpenAPI following [this link](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/docs/rest-api.md#examples).

So, you can generate a YAML file describing Argo Workflow resources and send it to the Kubernetes API as described in the examples.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

Argo 2.5 [introduces its own API](https://blog.argoproj.io/argo-workflows-v2-5-released-ce7553bfd84c).

There are currently officially-supported [Golang](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/pkg/apiclient/apiclient.go) and [Java](https://github.com/argoproj-labs/argo-client-java) clients. There is also a community-supported [Python](https://github.com/CermakM/argo-client-python) client. Updates will be available here: https://github.com/argoproj-labs/argo-client-gen

Argo provides Swagger API specs, so it should be reasonably easy to generate clients for other languages.

Comment: Is there documents for argo golang sdk?

Comment: @shuiqiang I haven't located any docs, but there is an example: https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/master/examples/example-golang/main.go
argoproj.slack.com is also pretty active.